# Get a Text in center of a image, with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some images inside `<a></a>` tags.

```
        @foreach($themes as $thema)
            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{ $thema->id }}">
                <span class="text">{{ $thema->thema }}</span>
                <img src="{{ $thema->picture }}">
            </a>
        @endforeach
```

Now between the `<a>` and the `<img>` tag, is a `{{ $thema->thema }}`. This just gives me some Names of topics. Like: Gaming, Health etc.... Now I have this Jquery code for my pictures:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('a img').animate({
            opacity:1
       });
       $('a img').hover(function(){
          $(this).stop().animate({opacity:.5}, 'fast');
       }, function(){
           $(this).stop().animate({opacity:1}, 'fast');
       });
    });
</script>
```

I've got this effect from this guy here:

But now I also want that if I enter the picture with my mouse, there also should be the name of the topic. So I need some Jquery code, that also gives me the topic and put it on the center of the picture while the opacity is on 50%.

I hope you all understood what I mean. My English isn't the best and I'm still learning Jquery.. So I need the right syntax for Jquery to get the text inside of the picture ( or Javascript/css solution )

How I did it before on a dirty css way:

```
img {
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 275px;
    height: 228px;
}

.text {
    margin-left: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    color: Black;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    width: 275px;
    height: 228px;
    line-height: 228px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: candara;
    font-size: 24px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    display: inline-block;
}

.text:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with CSS? If anything using jQuery is the "dirty" way...

Comment: well, it's more like if there are many layers with my css solution. first the pictures, then the effects with the text. If I'm trying to edit my pictures, allways the whole effect just moves to another place like the pictures are after the edits. So I allways need to fix that, using 'margin' commands. So I want to use Jquery. Now I can move my pictures how ever I want, the effect allways will follows my picture. It's just the text I need to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a snippet for you to demonstrate my solution. In my example, I use CSS and HTML without any JavaScript. This approach makes maintenance easier by keeping more of your design concerns in CSS. (Avoid styling and animation via JavaScript, if you can)

I used one of the common vertical centering techniques you can find [here](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/), but the process is: absolutely position a block 50% from the top of its container, then offset it up 50% of its own height using `transform: translateY(-50%);`.

Feel free to add your `<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{ $thema->id }}">` wrapper around the `<figure>` tags and insert your other template variables where you need them.

```css
.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.img {
  /* Change these as needed, everything else should resize appropriately */
  width: 275px;
  height: 228px;
}
.text-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.text {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: black;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: candara;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.img-wrapper:hover .text-wrapper {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<figure class="img-wrapper">
  <img class="img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ4V5.jpg" />
  <div class="text-wrapper">
    <figcaption class="text">some text</figcaption>
  </div>
</figure>
<figure class="img-wrapper">
  <img class="img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVOg3.jpg" />
  <div class="text-wrapper">
    <figcaption class="text">even more text than the last item so you can see how it flows</figcaption>
  </div>
</figure>
```